# Unable to lock a file, folder or branch in VS 2015 connected to Visual Studio team Services

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I am trying to lock a branch from Visual Studio 2015 which is connected to Visual studio Team Services. The locking succeeds, but when I am about to check-in, all the changes are undone and the check-in fails. I have all the permissions, to be double sure I have explicitly added myself as the admin and given all permissions on VSTS.

Here are the step by step screen shots of what is happening:

**1) I right click on the branch and select the lock option form source control.**
 [image: Right and selecting **lock** from source control]

**2) Lock popup opens up**
[image: lock popup opens up]

**3) I am about to check-in**

[image: I am about to check-in]

**4) The check-in fails, everything is undo-ed and a warning message is shown :** *All of the changes were either unmodified files or locks. The changes have been undone by the server.*
[image: check-in fails with a warning message]

I have also tried to modify a file, then lock it and then check it in. But it fails with the same message.

[The documentation for VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/lock-unlock-folders-files) indicates that there should have been an option to check out lock or check in lock in the lock popup in #3 image above, but that is not being shown to me, not matter what.

I just need to lock the branch to prevent further changes to it!

Comment: Locking only works when your workspace is configured as a server workspace. The default workspace type in 2015 is a local workspace. After locking a file only other users with a server workspace will be aware of the lock.

Comment: @jessehouwing Thanks. Is there any other way to prevent changes to the branch?

Comment: Permissions or checkin policies

Answer (score 0):

As Jesse said locking only works for server workspaces.

I has this problem at a client and created a TFVC Branch Policy checkin policy that allows you to configure locking based in a branch path or regex.

https://nkdagility.com/branch-policies-tfvc/